# In laravel 10 jetstream after Login it redirect me to dashboard even through RouteServiceProvider.php i write public const HOME = 'home';

Tags: laravel, redirect

i am trying to send user to different page after login . so i use laravel jetstream . but i do no want the user to be send to dashboard . so in the routeserviceprovider i wrote public const HOME = 'home'; But after login it still send me to dashboard . i want the user to go to the home.index . i think the problem is with the routeserviceprovider.php . but cant figure out what it is .i have tried to solved this more than 5 hours.

i also tried php artisan optimized:clear

here is the code from RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public const HOME = 'home';
```

here is my route

```
route::get('/home',[AdminController::class,'home']);
```

Here is my controller code

```
public function home()
{
    if(Auth::id())
    {
        $usertype = Auth()->user()->usertype;
        if($usertype == 'user')

        {
            return view('home.index');         
        }

        else
        {
            return view('admin.index');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check the `fortify.php` config file?

Comment: brother i don't know how to thank you . i was stuck with this error for a long time .. Thank you very much for your answer . Your answer solve my issue ..  There is no emoji here to show you how much i appreciate you.